# Unauthenticated identites not mapping to Developer Authenticated Identity

Tags: ios, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

When a user launches the app they are an unauthenticated user and they receive a `unauthenticated cognito identity` supplied from the DeveloperAuthenticatedIdentityProvider class in the iOS app.  I can see that `unauthenticated cognito identity` in the cognito console.  However, when they login and I make a call to my nodejs backend with a logins map of:

```
{
   DevAuthIdentityLogin:<username>
}
```

and using this backend code:

```
getCognitoIdentity: function(logins, cognitoId, error) {
        var cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity(awsOptions);

        var params = {
            IdentityPoolId: identityPool,
            Logins: logins,
            TokenDuration: (60 * 5)
        };

        cognitoidentity.getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack);
                error(err)
            } else {
                console.log(data);           // successful response
                cognitoId(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

It creates a new identity id with the `developer authenticated identity` and I can see that in the cognito console, but the old unauthenticated one is not being mapped to this new developer authenticated one.

Do I need to supply the `unauthenticated identity id` in the logins map when making a call to my backend to associate the two? OR am I not making this call correctly.  I need some clarification on how to map/merge these identities please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already answered your question on [our forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=652843), but you need to include the unauth identitity id as a parameter to the [GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity.html) call, otherwise Amazon Cognito will have no way of knowing that it should associate your user identifier to that identity.

Comment: Ya sorry, I wasn't sure which forum would get a response.  I've had questions go unanswered in the AWS forums so I figured both wouldn't hurt. Thank you, it worked.

Comment: P.S. This wasn't mentioned in the documentation and it should be, or if it was, it was ambiguous because I couldn't figure it out even after reading the documentation multiple times.

Comment: @YoshiTheCorgi No worries about cross-posting. Can you tell me which docs you reviewed? I'd definitely like to make sure we update the docs to better explain this.

Comment: Sure thing. I was reading through this [Doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/developer-authenticated-identities/)  I suppose `idRequest.setIdentityId("14232");` would be a reference to it.  But there isn't any mentions of what is need in terms of going from unauthenticated to developer authenticated.